# How to limit async task until theres no job in loop?

Tags: javascript

In my code i trying to learn async, i have 700 async task to do, the job will done in random time.

My question how to limit async task in loop?

Let say i want it to do 30 job at start time. and watch event each async task done it will start 1 task to fill limit task 30 at time again until 700 task, or theres no task again.

For now loop will execute all async task in same time. its not i want.

```
function JobdeskAsync(){
    console.log(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
}

function finishedTime(max, min){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;
}

for ( let i = 0; i < 700; i++){
    setTimeout(JobdeskAsync, finishedTime(5000, 1000));
}
```

Comment: That is called an async pool, [here](https://github.com/rxaviers/async-pool/) is an example.

Answer (score 0):

@Wendelin has a great example there. For how it directly applies to your application, you currently are:

- Looping through 700 asynchronous Jobs
- Executing them all immediately (to finish as and when)

What you need to do is be able to recognise when you have reached your pool maximum (30) and not add/execute any more until that pool depletes. I'm not writing the code for you because there's a thousand ways to do it, but at it's base what you need:

1. Functionality to store executing jobs (call it a "store")
2. Functionality to add jobs to the store
3. Functionality to see if that store is full
4. Combine 2/3 so that when #3 is not true you can do #2

Answer (score 0):

You need to start 30 jobs that continue processing data until there is no more.
Here there is a queue of data that each job pulls from.  If there is no data left, it returns a simple promise that resolves to 'done'.  If there is data, it processes it and returns the promise from a new call to createJob().

```js
const queue = [];

// fill queue with data to process
for (let i = 0; i < 70; i++) {
  queue.push(i);
}

function createJob() {
  // pull data to work on from the queue
  const data = queue.shift();
  
  // if no data is remaining, return promsie that resolves to 'done'
  if (data === undefined) {
    return Promise.resolve('done');
  }
  
  // otherwise we do some work on the data
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // simulate work by waiting 500-1500ms
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`handled ${data}`);
      // this resolves our promise with another promise, createJob()
      resolve(createJob());
    }, 500 + Math.random() * 1000);
  });
}

// create 30 jobs and wait for all to complete, each job will
// create a new job when it has finished and chain the results
const jobs = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  jobs.push(createJob());
}

console.log('30 jobs running...');
Promise.all(jobs).then(() => console.log('ALL JOBS COMPLETED'));
```